# How to refresh the Kendo Grid automaically after doing update

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am using the kendo Grid with inline editing ,after editing the field by clicking the update button the field in the grid is not triggering to non editable mode it is still editable i.e it is not refreshing the Grid, after manually refreshing the page am getting the updated data. I have this script to do refresh

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.refresh();
```

but it is not firing, even I have done this one

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({   
  ...............
  pageable: {refresh: true,},
  ...........
                  });
```

but this one also not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can refresh page by calling requestEnd function and also you can check whether its update read create or destroy

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
               dataSource:...,
                ..
                ..
                ,
                requestEnd: onRequestEnd
            })

function onRequestEnd(e) {
          if (e.type == "create") {
                e.sender.read();
          }
          else if (e.type == "update") {
                e.sender.read();
          }
 }
```

Hope this will help you